# My web-app installs as extension on Chrome Store

Tags: google-chrome, chrome-web-store

I published a program on the chrome web store, and it installs as an extension, instead of showing icon on the chrome home page.

How do I stop the program installing as extension and make it install as an installable web app?

I dont see any options in the upload options page.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably working on a packaged app, which is something new and frequently changing (by google's spec).

look at: http://developer.chrome.com/apps/first_app.html

Some things to make sure:

- your manifest indicates this is a packaged app
- that once you've uploaded the app that the chrome dashboard indicates this is a packaged app

---

given the age of the question, your circumstances will have changed between then and now. packaged apps are now much more mature than they were 7 months ago.

Comment: hey thanks - I never sorted it out.  Ijust couldnt get it to work.  Ill look again to see if this works.  Thanks!